# Can Visual Studio be configured to automatically set WinDbg .sympath & .srcpath?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windbg, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

I Use Visual Studio 2017 to do kernel debugging on a target PC.

Each time I attach the debugger, I have to manually add the paths to the relevant source code and symbols in order for breakpoints to hit.

In the Debugger Immediate Window:

```
>> .srcpath+ <path to source files>

>> .sympath+ <path to .pdb files>
```

In regular user mode debugging, VS is able to this automatically. Is it possible to make it happen automatically?

Comment: Are you looking for _NT_SYMBOL_PATH and _NT_SOURCE_PATH? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/general-environment-variables)

Comment: I don't think so. I use _NT_SYMBOL_PATH to point to the microsoft symbol path. I can indeed set these to point to my files paths but these change between debug sessions.

Comment: In "regular" user mode debugging, the EXE file has a link to the PDBs and the PDBs have a link to the source files. Also, you have a solution open, so it knows the source path already. You can do the same with WinDbg by saving a workspace.

Comment: Yes, so I was wondering if this workspace could also be saved in VS. apparently not.